# Number of different values that obtain from a given set

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Suppose $S=\{1,2,\dots,7\}$, already we know that, $S$ have $2^7$ subsets. But the problem is, when we multiply elements of each subset $S$, how many different value we can obtain from multiplication of elements of each subsets? In $2^7$ subsets, some of them are equal, for example, for subset of size 2, $3\times 4=6\times 2$. Are there a simple way that eliminate the duplicate values for any subsets?

Comment: It's usually nice to add some context (from where is this problem) and some thoughts or early attempts you've done. As a hint, I'd start with writing the possible factorizations in primes of numbers you can obtain from the set $S$.

Comment: Every number you get is a divisor of $7!=5040$. But you can't get every divisor of $5040$, e.g., you can't get $9$. That should get you started.

Comment: That is already a huge hint.  The hint in more words again is that the odd multiples of $9$  who are divisors of $7!$ are not possible.  Can you think of any others who are not possible?  Can you prove that?  Note that the only prime factors possible in the results are $2,3,5,7$ which limits the search considerably.

Comment: Now... $7! = 2^4\cdot 3^2\cdot 5\cdot 7$... The number of factors of a number is well known to be the product of one more than each of the exponents in the prime factorization... in this case $(4+1)\cdot (2+1)\cdot (1+1)\cdot (1+1)=5\cdot 3\cdot 2\cdot 2 = 60$, and the number of these which are not possible you can count simply as well and remove from the count.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $1$ has no effect in the multiplications you can put it aside. Put the number $6$ aside for now. Factorize all the other numbers. The multiplication of the elements of any nonempty subset of $\lbrace 2, 3, 4, 5, 7 \rbrace$ would be of the form
$$2^{x} \times 3^{y} \times 5^{z} \times 7^{w} $$ where $x$ and $y$ and $z$ and $w$ are whole numbers and $0 \leq x \leq 3$ and $0 \leq y \leq 1$ and $0 \leq z \leq 1$ and $0 \leq w \leq 1$. As a result of the multiplication principle, you can say that there are $4 \times 2 \times 2 \times 2 = 32$ such multiplications. Now what if we play the number $6$ into the game? Then any multiplication would be of the form
$$2^{x + 1} \times 3^{y + 1} \times 5^{z} \times 7^{w} $$ where $x$ and $y$ and $z$ and $w$ are whole numbers and $0 \leq x \leq 3$ and $0 \leq y \leq 1$ and $0 \leq z \leq 1$ and $0 \leq w \leq 1$. However, if $0 \leq x \leq 2$ and $y = 0$ no new state will be generated and vice versa so you should suppose either $x = 3$ or $y = 1$. You can deduce from the inclusion-exclusion principle that the number of the new states will be $2 \times 2 \times 2 + 4 \times 2 \times 2 \; - 2 \times 2 = 20$. So overall the answer would be $32 + 20= 52$.

Comment: You overcounted the divisor $1$.  It appeared in not only your first case (*where you considered only the divisor $1$*) but also in your second case where you considered divisors of the form $2^x3^y5^z7^w$ in the case of $x=y=z=w=0$.  Note, the empty-product is equal to $1$.

Comment: Yes. I made a mistake. You're right. I'll edit it. Good point.

Comment: @Emad, I wish you had let OP work it out from the comments, instead of spoiling the fun by writing it all out yourself.

Comment: @GerryMyerson That's right. I should pay more attention to these things.

Answer (score 2):

$7!=2^4\cdot 3^2\cdot 5^1\cdot 7^1$ has $(4+1)(2+1)(1+1)(1+1)=60$ divisors

Of these, the divisors who are multiples of $2^4$ but not multiples of $3$ are not possible to make (*as $6$ would have been needed for that last factor of $2$ and would have brought a factor of $3$ along with it*) as well as the divisors who are multiples of $9$ but not multiples of $2$ are not possible (*for a similar reason*).

There are $2\cdot 2 = 4$ factors who are multiples of $2^4$ but not multiples of $3$ (*seen by looking at factors of the form $2^4\cdot 3^0\cdot 5^z\cdot 7^w$*) and similarly there are $2\cdot 2 = 4$ factors who are multiples of $9$ but not multiples of $2$ (*looking at $2^0\cdot 3^2\cdot 5^z\cdot 7^w$*).

As such the total will be

$$60 - 4-4 = 52$$